# Multiple Sub Level SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that contains two tables.  The first is a list of part numbers while the second is a list of components associated with the parent part.

Table 1 - **Inv**

- StockCode
- ProductClass

Table 2 - **Bom**

- ParentPart
- Component
- QtyPer

The third table is a basic Sales order detail table.

The blow SQL command returns all of the items found in the Bom table that contains a part with Product Class 'FG'.

```
    SELECT     SD.SalesOrderLine, SD.StockCode, SD.BackOrderQty*Bom.QtyPer AS TotalReq, 
               Bom.Component, SD.MLineShipDate
    FROM       SalesOrder SD
    JOIN       Bom ON SD.StockCode=Bom.ParentPart
    JOIN       Inv On BS.Component=Inv.StockCode
    WHERE      SD.SalesOrder=xxxxx
    AND        Inv.ProductClass='FG'
```

The problem that I now have is that some of the returned Component parts may well contain an entry in the Bom table as a Parent Part as well.  As a result I need to return all items that appear with the 'FG' class under the initial Parent Part with the appropriate total qty for each.  This may not return any results, but at the same time, could return between 1 and 4 sub layers of query.

**Sample Data**

**Inv**

- Part1, 'FG'
- Part2, 'RM'
- Part3, 'RM'
- Part4, 'FG'
- Part5, 'RM'
- Part6, 'FG'
- Part7, 'RM'
- Part8, 'RM'
- Part9, 'FG'
- Part10, 'RM'
- Part11, 'FG'
- Part12, 'FG'

**Bom**

- Part1, Part2, 1
- Part1, Part3, 1
- Part1, Part4, 1
- Part4, Part5, 2
- Part1, Part6, 2
- Part6, Part7, 1
- Part6, Part8, 1
- Part6, Part9, 3
- Part9, Part10, 1
- Part9, Part11, 1
- Part11, Part12, 1

Base on this data, an order processed for 2 off of "Part1" should return the following

**Results**

- 1, Part1, 2, Part4, dd/mm/yy
- 1, Part1, 4, Part6, dd/mm/yy
- 1, Part6, 12, Part9, dd/mm/yy
- 1, Part9, 12, Part11, dd/mm/yy

Comment: Please, provide some data sample and output that you need.

Comment: @gofr1, I have added some sample data.

Comment: Thanks! It is great! One question: You mention Part 1, 4, 6,9 and 11, and what about Part2 and Part3, there are in `Bom` table with Part1 in first column

Comment: Because their part code is "RM" I do not need to return these.

Comment: And one more question: what is 1 before Part1 and 2,4,12,12 after other parts, and dd/mm/yy? And how about Part11 and Part12 there are both FG.

Comment: The "1" would be the Sales Order Line input and the "dd/mm/yy" the date of the order.  I've tried to keep the formatting the same as the query as it stands.  Thanks.

Comment: Finally, add my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  CAST(NULL as nvarchar(6)) as Parent,
        StockCode as Child,
        ProductClass
FROM Inv 
WHERE StockCode = 'Part1'
UNION ALL
SELECT  b.ParentPart,
        b.Component,
        i.ProductClass
FROM Bom b
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.Child = b.ParentPart
INNER JOIN Inv i
    ON i.StockCode = b.Component AND i.ProductClass = c.ProductClass
)

SELECT  *
FROM cte
WHERE Parent IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
Parent  Child   ProductClass
Part1   Part4   FG
Part1   Part6   FG
Part6   Part9   FG
Part9   Part11  FG
Part11  Part12  FG
```

You can remove `WHERE` statement from CTE in order to get all hierarchy. And join this CTE with another table.